# Asymptotic behaviour of Pythagorean hypotenuses

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Consider

$$H_{\text{prim}} =\{c\in\mathbb{N}^{+}\mid\exists{a,b\in\mathbb{N}^{+}:~}a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2},\ \operatorname{gcd}(a,b,c)=1\}\overset{\text{Eukl.}}{=}\{c\in\mathbb{N}^{+}\mid\exists{u,v\in\mathbb{N}^{+}:~}c=u^{2}+v^{2},\ \operatorname{gcd}(u,v)=1\},$$

the set of hypotenuses${}^{\ast}$ of **primitive** Pythagorean-triples. Then it holds, thanks to Lambek-Moser, *et al.*, that $h_{\text{prim}}(x):=|H_{\text{prim}}\cap[0,x)|\sim\frac{1}{2\pi}x$ for $x$ large.

Consider now simply

$$H =\{c\in\mathbb{N}^{+}\mid\exists{a,b\in\mathbb{N}^{+}:~}a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}\},$$

the set of hypoteneuse of Pythagorean-triples. Obviously $H\supset H_{\text{prim}}$. The question remains, what the asymptotic behaviour of $h(x):=H\cap[0,x)$ is.

Are there any papers on this?

Comment: You wrote "hypoteneuse" for plural of "hypothenuse". Sounds good !

Comment: plural is hippopotami

Comment: Will: I wrote $c^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}$ in keeping with the rudimentary definition. It just holds thanks to Euklid, that $\exists{a,b\in\mathbb{N}^{+}:~}a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2},\ \operatorname{gcd}(a,b,c)=1$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\exists{u,v\in\mathbb{N}^{+}:~}u^{2}+v^{2}=c,\ \operatorname{gcd}(u,v)=1$. The problem remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is some sort of problem with your first claim. The hypoteneuse $c$ of a primitive Pythagorean triple is an odd number that can be written as
$$  c = r^2 + s^2  $$
with $\gcd(r,s) = 1.$ The number of such $c$ up to some positive $x$ is proportional to 
$$ \frac{x}{\sqrt {\log x}}  $$ 
It is the same for numbers $t$ that can be written as $t = u^2 + v^2$ but not necessarily coprime, but with a larger coefficient, that being $0.7642.$ This is in the final few pages of the second volume in [LeVeque](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486425398.html).

For primitive, the constant coefficient is a little smaller. I asked about that, let me find the question.

[Asymptotic for primitive sums of two squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282550/asymptotic-for-primitive-sums-of-two-squares)

At some point in 2012 I saved jpegs of four relevant pages from the Dover edition of LeVeque.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot about the root-log-part, which does come up. I'll have a look at LeVeque (I read a book of his a long time ago). Thanks for the tip and the two links!

Comment: Arrgh, I cannot access the mentioned book from le Veque. I have one from Erdös, but he unfortunately does not go into much detail on the above mentioned asymptotic result. Can one achieve the result with that product formula in the other `stackexchange` post?

Comment: @Thomas, posted some pages. I hit control plus once or twice to enlarge on my screen, seem fairly readable. His proof of 7-28 does not name any explicit lemmas used, that is no guarantee that it is self contained.

Comment: @"Will Jagy". Thanks! Theorem 7-28 is the one. What is the exakt definition of $B(n)$? Is this the number of integers in $[1,n]$, that let themselve be written als a sum of squares?

Comment: @Thomas, yes, from the first paragraph of section 7-5, on page 257, "we shall obtain an asymptotic estimate for $B(x),$ the number of integers not exceeding $x$ which can be written as a sum of two squares." Then he gives a heuristic argument until part way onto page 259.

Comment: Okay. Another small point: that product, which defines the constant $B$ is that explicitly $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\prod_{r\in\mathbb{P}}(1-r^{-2})^{-1/2}$? If so, this is nothing other than $\sqrt{\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}} =\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$ and this in turn is $\approx 0.906899682117109$, a bit different from your $0.7642\ldots$, unless there’s something more to this?

Comment: @Thomas, somewhere it should say that $r$ means primes $3 \pmod 4.$ Yes, page 259, "Using $q$ and $r$ to denote primes congruent to $1$ and $3 \pmod 4$ respectively"

Comment: @Thomas, this is why having a few actual books is a good thing. What would be German for "treeware?"

Comment: Okay, and sorry, one last question, from $B(x) \sim Cx/\log(x)$, one can conclude for instance, that $B(x)~/~(Cx/\log(x))\longrightarrow 1$, *etc.*, or does LeVeque / do Numbertheorists mean something else with the statement (*i. e.* other than the Big-$\mathcal{O}$ notation)? Do you mean freeware? Gratis Software. Man benutzt aber sowieso das Englische „Freeware“. Yeah, I have a bookshelf full of books, a lot for maths, but not much numbertheory.

Comment: it should mean that the ratio goes to $1,$ but not much is being said about the size of the difference; sometimes the error term (the difference) is not much smaller than the main term. In any case, it is true that $B(x) / x \rightarrow 0.$ Oh page 263, $$ B(x) = \frac{Bx}{\sqrt {\log x}} + O \left( \frac{x}{\log^{3/4}x}  \right) $$

Comment: Oh, right, my mistake, the statement $f(x) = g(x) + O(h(x))$ means exactly, that $\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{|h(x)|}<\infty$ and as a consequence of which (with a loss in information along the way) in our case $\frac{B(x)-Bx/\sqrt{\log(x)}}{x}\longrightarrow 0$, *etc.* Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Thomas, no, just as people call the U. S. postal service "snailmail" as opposed to various computer communication methods, some people who read only things online refer to newspapers or books, made out of paper, which comes from wood pulp from trees, "treeware."