# Sum of two coprime squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282550/asymptotic-for-primitive-sums-of-two-squares) it is stated that

> A positive integer $n$ can be written primitively as the sum of two squares, meaning $n = x^2 + y^2$ with $\gcd(x,y)=1,$ precisely when $n$ is not divisible by $4$ or by any prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$

I am looking for a proof of this statement.

**What I have done:** I can show that, if $n=x^2+y^2$ with $\gcd(x,y)=1$, any prime factor $p$ of $n$ is congruent to $1\pmod{4}$. But, I am stuck on how to prove that $n$ is also not divisible by $4$ in this case, in addition to the converse implication. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The converse starts with Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares (and links therein).

Answer (score 1):

If both $x,y$ are odd, then $x^2+y^2\equiv 2\pmod4$, so if $4\,|\,x^2+y^2$, then both $x,y$ have to be even.