# Given the numbers integrally represented by $x^2 - n y^2,$ what proportion are represented by $x^2 - n^3 y^2 $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

A young man wrote to me about asymptotics of the set of numbers represented integrally by $x^2 - n^3 y^2 $  when we assume that we know asymptotics for $x^2 - n y^2.$  I made  several suggestions, of the same type as in my question  [Asymptotic for primitive sums of two squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282550/asymptotic-for-primitive-sums-of-two-squares)   ,  along with discussion of the class number (of indefinite  binary quadratic forms) $h(4 n^3)$  as a multiple of $h(4n).$  However, I did not settle the manner, and I don't know  analytic number theory.

The computer experiments I've been doing are inconclusive. For example, I've been finding the count of numbers from $-N$  to $N$  of $x^2 - 21 y^2,$  as opposed to $x^2 - 9261 y^2.$  For modest $N$ the ratio was about 3, which is the ratio of the class numbers. As I increased $N$ the ratio began increasing, also for primitive representations. Oh, the ratio of class numbers really is the ratio for represented **primes.**

Cute fact:  the multiplier of the class number is tied to the Pell equation. Given $n,$   find the fundamental solution to $t^2 - n u^2 = 1.$  The multiplier is just $\gcd(n,u),$   as in $h(4 n^3) =  \gcd(n,u) h(4n) \;  .   $  Who knew?

**The question**:  given numbers  integrally represented by $x^2 - n y^2,$  what proportion are represented by $x^2 - n^3 y^2  \; \;  \; \;$  and does it make any difference if we insist on primitive representations?

Comment: Why doesn't $x^2-n^3y^2=x^2-n(ny)^2$ immediately resolve this?

Comment: @HankScorpio  It could be. Let me try some experiments with very small $n,$   such as $x^2 - 2 y^2$   and $x^2 - 8 y^2$

Comment: Well, comparing $x^2 - 3 y^2$ with $x^2 - 27 y^2,$  taking values between $-100,000,000$ and $100,000,000.$   The former got ( using my variable bounds)  $ 21,391,672$   numbers. The latter got  $16,565,860,$   with ratio of big/small   at $1.29131$